# Getting error while running the script dynamically using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am getting the following error while trying to run the script dynamically using Jquery.

> Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery.js:339
    at Function.globalEval (jquery.js:339)
    at m.fn.init.domManip (jquery.js:5985)
    at m.fn.init.append (jquery.js:5758)
    at m.fn.init.<anonymous> (jquery.js:5884)
    at m.access (jquery.js:4157)
    at m.fn.init.html (jquery.js:5848)
    at test (xss1.html:10)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (xss1.html:18)
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:339
globalEval @ jquery.js:339
domManip @ jquery.js:5985
append @ jquery.js:5758
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:5884
m.access @ jquery.js:4157
html @ jquery.js:5848
test @ xss1.html:10
onclick @ xss1.html:18
```

I am explaining my code below.

```js
function test(){
    var txtUserInput=document.getElementById('txtUserInput').value;
    //var txtUserInput = 'test<script>alert(1)<\/script>';
    $("#firstDiv").html(
       "This is bold:<b>"+txtUserInput+"</b>"
    );
}
$('#btntext').click(function() {
  test()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Demo</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
    </script>
</head>
<body>
   <input type="text" name="val" id="txtUserInput">
   <button id="btntext" onclick="test();">Test</button>
   <div id="firstDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here I have `//var txtUserInput = 'test<script>alert(1)<\/script>';` in comment line and its running fine,giving the alert prompt but when same input `i.e-test<script>alert(1)<\/script>` passing from input field its not working means the alert prompt is not showing. I need if I am passing the same value from the text box it should work like when its setting as static value.

Comment: There's no need to escape the `/` in the script's closing tag.

Comment: Please don’t tell me it’s a coincidence that someone else asked something very similar only an hour ago, with code that looks largely similar to yours, too ... https://stackoverflow.com/q/48986159/1427878

Comment: @CBroe I think it is a coincidence

Comment: @CBroe yes i think it is a coincidence - those users have got more than 1k rep